# TWebBrowser <select><option> clicked

Tags: delphi, combobox, html-select, twebbrowser

I'm trying to use a TWebBrowser to display the results of a query in an old Delphi 6 program. Each row has a combobox (HTML "select") which lists a number of actions the user can perform. Using the CommandStateChange event I can work out which row and which item was selected in the combobox. However, the event fires even when the combo is simply dropped down - ie nothing specifically selected by the user yet. I'm not entirely sure this is the right event to be honest!

So, given some partial HTML like this:

```
<td><select id="row1">
  <option value="option1">Run</option>
  <option value="option2">Jump</option>
</select></td>
<td><select id="row2">
  <option value="option1">Run</option>
  <option value="option2">Jump</option>
</select></td>
```

and some code:

```
procedure TFooListV2Form.WebBrowserCommandStateChange(Sender: TObject; Command: Integer; Enable: WordBool);
var
    Doc: IHTMLDocument2;        // document object
    Sel: IHTMLSelectionObject;  // current selection
    selectElement : IHTMLSelectElement;
begin
    // Check we have a valid web browser triggering this event
    if not Assigned(Sender) or not (Sender is TWebBrowser) then
        Exit;

    // Check we have required command
    if TOleEnum(Command) <> CSC_UPDATECOMMANDS then
        Exit;

    // Get ref to document object and check not nil
    Doc := WebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
    if not Assigned(doc) then
        Exit;

    Caption := '';
    if Assigned(doc.activeElement) then begin
        if supports(doc.activeElement, IHTMLSelectElement) then begin
            selectElement := doc.activeElement as IHTMLSelectElement;
            Caption := doc.activeElement.id + selectElement.value;
        end;
    end;

end;
```

gives results like:

```
row1option1
```

which is great. However, with the combobox collapsed, I get the first result in the combobox upon expansion, before the user actually selects an option. I do subsequently get the correct result.

So, how do I detect that the user has actually clicked on an item? Many thanks.

Comment: can you remeber previousl;y selected items for all the comboboxes and just check if after the click event the selection changed ?

Comment: Interesting idea, however, CommandStateChanged gets triggered twice - once when the combobox is dropped down (with the incorrect result), and once when an item is selected. One might say that I should use the second event but to me that seems far too unreliable.